# Can You Define a Custom Validation Set With Scikit-Learn's GradientBoostingRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

As per the question title, I'd like to know if there's a way to specify a custom validation set for Scikit-Learn's `GradientBoostingRegressor`?  I think the answer is no, but I figured I'd check.

On their [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.fit) it states that the `validation_fraction` argument only accepts a float as an argument, so I'm guessing there's no direct way to create your own validation set and use that.

Does anyone know if there's a way to do this?  Being able to create your own validation set is a reason why I typically use xgboost, but sometimes sklearn is better for what I need.  I'd settle for at least being able to use some of the custom splitter classes in the library if I couldn't create the validation set directly.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

The main purpose of being able to supply the custom validation set is to use it in conjunction with the early stopping feature, which was not noted above.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use sklearn metrics and sklearn .predict method. A pseudo-code for this kind of a problem would be:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test ==CustomSplitMethod(X,y)
model= GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=0)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
prediction=model.predict(X_test)
evaluation_metric(prediction,y_test)# For example ///sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(prediction,y_test)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to use the validation during early-stopping

Comment: I've searched many sources (probably as you did), and there isn't an option like that; an alternative might be simulating early stoping with a for a loop by monitoring evaluation metric outside of the GradientBoostingR.